# Show that for every natural number $n$ there exists a unique natural number $m$ such that $n$ lies between the sum of $m$ and $m-1$ numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How do we show that for every $n$ $\epsilon$ $N$, there exists a unique $m$ $\epsilon$ $N$such that $n$ can be expressed as $$\frac{m(m-1)}{2}<n \le\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am assuming $\mathbb{N} = \{ 1,2,...\}$

For $m \in \mathbb{N}$ Set $$I_{m} = (\frac{m(m-1)}{2}, \frac{m(m+1)}{2}].$$

note that for $a<b$

$$1) \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }I_{a}\cap I_{b} = \emptyset$$

as $\frac{b(b-1)}{2} \geq \frac{a(a+1)}{2}$ and the left endpoint of each $I_m$ is not inside $I_{m}$. Furthermore

$$\bigcup_{m=1}^{j}I_{m} = (0, \frac{j(j+1)}{2}] \rightarrow (0, \infty]\text{ as }j\rightarrow \infty$$

thus each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is in some $I_{p}$ where $p$ must be unique by $1)$

Comment: And of course the same comment applies here (and to some other answers of yours): please do not answer such low quality questions. The proper behavior is to encourage the poster to improve the question.

Comment: Okay... From next time I will not answer questions that have 0 upvotes.

Comment: Thanks for you understanding. But note that it's not the number of upvotes that determine whether a question is of good quality. It's totally fine to answer a question with $0$ upvote, as long as it's a [good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Okay...So I will see if the asker of the question asks something like "I managed to show $1+1 = 2$ using $\textit{some theorem}$ how do I show $2+1 = 3$" I will assume it is a good question.

Comment: I would say yes, it would be acceptable if the asker shows at least some effort in trying to solve the problem. This could be as simple as stating a relevant definition or theorem.